# How to push a new branch to a public project

Tags: git, github

I'm attempting to push a bug fix to a public project on github using https

```
git clone <repo's https url>
git checkout -b <branch>
git add <modified file>
git commit -m "message"
git push --set-upstream origin <branch>
```

I get:

```
remote: Permission to <repo> denied to <user>.
fatal: unable to access <repo>: The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I can see that many other users have pushed branches to this repo, then one of the project admins potentially accepts the change and merges to master. What am I potentially doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a merge request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076923/what-is-a-merge-request)

Comment: your master branch is protected...create a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can push branches to a public repo, if you are added as a contributor to that project. Otherwise, the process to contribute would be to create and clone a *fork*, make your changes and push to the fork. Then you can create pull requests from the fork to main project for the author to review and take action.