# Whether Merge Request only refers to two different repo?

Tags: git, github

In Git, we often hear about `Merge Request`, and I also find [What's Merge Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666408/7693832) question in SO.

I want to know whether the MR only refers two different repo(no matter whether one is forked from another)?

Comment: You can also have a "merge request" within the same repository. There's nothing that requires it to be between two different repositories. It's a cohesive series of changes (i.e. changeset) that can originate from anywhere.

Comment: I did not find an example of using MR in one repo.

Comment: You do it all the time, take GitLab for example: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/

Comment: @244boy, an example of a merge request within the same repository is when you want to merge from another branch (e.g. `feature1`) back into your main one (i.e. `master`). You'd open the merge request stating that both the source and target are implicitly from the same repository because you're just dealing with branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Merge Request" is the [GitLab way](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) of talking about what was originally ["Pull Request" in GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) (they are [basically the same](https://blog.scope.ink/untitledhttps-blog-scope-ink-pull-request-vs-merge-request-difference/))

In both case, they can be done between any two branches of a repository (or across forked repositories)

I often see merge request within one repository as a way to enforce basic code review (meaning: nothing is merged directly, but goes through a merge request review, and its associated comments/discussion)